# How can a list's lists be modified efficiently to have equal length to the list's longest list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 2-D list of shape `(300,000, X)`, where each of the sublists has a different size. In order to convert the data to a Tensor, all of the sublists need to have equal length, but I don't want to lose any data from my sublists in the conversion.

That means that I need to fill all sublists smaller than the longest sublist with filler (`-1`) in order to create a rectangular array. For my current dataset, the longest sublist is of length 5037.

My conversion code is below:

```
for seq in new_format:
    for i in range(0, length-len(seq)):
        seq.append(-1)
```

However, when there are 300,000 sequences in `new_format`, and `length-len(seq)` is generally >4000, the process is extraordinarily slow. How can I speed this process up or get around the issue efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual `append` calls can be rather slow, so use `list` multiplication to create the whole filler value at once, then concatenate it all at once, e.g.:

```
for seq in new_format:
    seq += [-1] * (length-len(seq))
```

`seq.extend([-1] * (length-len(seq)))` would be equivalent (trivially slower due to generalized method call approach, but likely unnoticeable given size of real work).

In theory, `seq.extend(itertools.repeat(-1, length-len(seq)))` would avoid the potentially large temporaries, but IIRC, the actual CPython implementation of `list.__iadd__`/`list.extend` forces the creation of a temporary `list` anyway (to handle the case where the generator is defined in terms of the `list` being extended), so it wouldn't actually avoid the temporary.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have another issue...I run out of RAM quickly with two arrays of size (350,000, 5000) for input and output data. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @EvanWeissburg: I have no special insight into tensorflow, but if tensors are anything like `numpy` arrays, odds are you could construct partial tensors and concatenate occasionally (so you'd make a 1000x# tensor, then concatenate another 1000x# tensor, and so on, until you had a 300,000x# tensor). By throwing away `list`s as soon as the partial tensor is constructed, you'd avoid excessive memory use (assuming tensors, like `numpy` arrays, store C level low memory overhead arrays of primitive types). I'd suggest a separate question for this (in general, one question per question is good form).